# In need of entry for BROWSCAP.INI that helps detect IE 9

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, internet-explorer-9

An application under IIS6 on a Win 2003 server uses BROWSCAP.INI to detect browser and version, but it hasn't yet been updated to detect IE 9, so the code checking for browser and vesion can't find anything and presents an error message to the user that they need IE 4 or greater.  I have been unable to find the information on MSDN or in a web search.

I did manage to find an entry on the IIS blog that said IIS7 detects both IE8 and IE9 just fine, but darn it we're still running IIS6.

Does anyone have or know where I can find the code for the BROWSCAP.INI that enables detection of IE9?

**Edited to add:** incidentally, I made what seemed would be the obvious additions to the text of BROWSCAP.INI (e.g. adding a node that reads:

```
[IE 9.0]
browser=IE
Version=9.0
majorver=#9
minorver=#0
frames=True
tables=True
cookies=True
backgroundsounds=True
vbscript=True
javaapplets=True
javascript=True
ActiveXControls=True
Win16=False
AK=False
SK=False
AOL=False
Update=False
```

... and this doesn't make any difference.

**Edited further to add:**

What is running on the web server in question is a classic ASP script in VBScript that uses the MSWC component to retrieve from IIS information on which browser the user is using.  When the user's browser "hits" the server up for a file, it passes along this information to IIS via the "HTTP_USER_AGENT" string.  IIS parses out the relevant information using its browscap.dll component and the browscap.ini file to do so.

Some sample code:

```
set objBrowserType = Server.CreateObject("MSWC.BrowserType")
```

MSWC.BrowserType passes an object with a number of properties, including the identity of the browser and its version, as well as other properties such as whether it understands javascript, and so on.  The problem is, it is not detecting IE 9 properly and this seems most likely to be because the browscap.ini file doesn't contain the relevant information required to help it do so.

Comment: It's hard for anybody to help if you do not tell us what the app is that uses the browscap.ini file.  I don't think that this is at all any sort of windows standard file.

Comment: BROWSCAP.INI isn't any sort of windows standard file?  You've got to be kidding.  It is IIS itself that uses the BROWSCAP.INI file to help parse out what browser the user has come in with.  Check http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311227 that describes the use of the file with IE 6.  Check any windows web server for the file, which at least in Win2003 and below is found in c:\windows\system32\inetsrv

Comment: Sorry, I am not running IIS and did an complete scan for the file on my system.

Comment: No problem @mdpc.  The file in question would generally only be found on windows web servers running a version of IIS.  It's part of the installation process for IIS.

Comment: Have you tried this guy? http://browsers.garykeith.com/home

Comment: @RobertMoir, please put your response in an answer so I can Accept it.  I found an up-to-date browscap.ini file on the site most ricky-tick and it worked just great.  Thanks!

Comment: @Cyberherbalist glad to have helped and answer done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a fairly good website that maintains up to date browscap.ini files [here](http://browsers.garykeith.com/home).

It's also worth mentioning for anyone else searching for this kind of thing that they supply data to [drupal](http://drupal.org/project/browscap) and are [referenced](https://www.php.net/function.get-browser) by the people running the php project.